# How to use iterate variable in case statement [VHDL]

Tags: vhdl

I want to generate my register interface, because I have several instance (channels) of the same peripheral.

```
while (I < generic_num_of_instances) loop
  case loc_addr is
    when 0 + I*256 =>
      q_ctrl_reg(I, 31 downto 0) <= s_axi_wdata;
  end case;
  I := I + 1;
end loop;
```

And it says: Error: Case choice must be locally static expression.

How can I generate this register interface? Should I use less descriptive if/elseif statements?

[image: the error message]

Comment: This code looks pretty strange, what is the end goal? If you're trying to describe a memory array, you should take a look at the HDL coding guidelines for your tool chain, and see how it advises you do this. A `case` statement does not at first glance seem at all suitable.

Comment: Prove a [mcve] which will include declarations. Note you can't slice a multi-dimensional array. You're also producing a combinational latch enable for the selected q_ctrl_reg.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew mentioned two important improvements, your case target must be a static expression (whose type is a locally static type) and if you are doing synthesis, you need to use a for loop.

Next, you cannot slice a multi-dimensional array, hence, q_ctrl_reg(I, 31 downto 0) is also invalid.  Lets fix that by using an array of an array (shown below):

```
type q_ctrl_reg_type is array (0 to MAX_REG -1) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ; 
signal q_ctrl_reg : q_ctrl_reg_type ;
```

Now lets put it all together, lets us a for loop instead of the while loop and an if statement instead of your case statement:

```
for i in 0 to generic_num_of_instances - 1 loop
  if loc_addr = 0 + I*256 then
      q_ctrl_reg(I) <= s_axi_wdata;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Or use Verilog.

Case choices is VHDL have to be *locally static* - that is they have to be *literals*, *constants* or *generics*. That isn't the case with Verilog.

You're also going to find that you need a `when others` branch, which will negate any improved readability gained using a case statement. (And given such a coding style is rather unusual anyway, I'd question whether it was ever more readable.)

Comment: And, while you're at it, I'd stick to `for` loops for synthesis. (Your `while` loop appears to be basically a `for` loop, anyway.)

Comment: I'll just point out in passing that Verilog `case` statements are simply syntactic sugar for `if/else` statements, which is an inevitable consequence of allowing variable choices. The first matching choice wins in Verilog, and this leads to stupidity like `full_case/parallel_case`. This doesn't happen in languages like VHDL (and, yes, C, which also requires constant choices).

Answer (score -1):

try making that "0 + I*256" value equal to a variable that you name in the loop i.e.

```
while (I < generic_num_of_instances) loop
    variable A : integer;
begin
A := 0 + I*256;
  case loc_addr is
    when A =>
      q_ctrl_reg(I, 31 downto 0) <= s_axi_wdata;
  end case;
  I := I + 1;
end loop;
```

hopefully this should work

Comment: I doubt that solves it - your case choice is still not locally static.

Comment: `A` is still a variable

Comment: Also a loop statement with a while iteration scheme does not have a declarative region (where variable A is declared, See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.10 Loop statement, 12.1 Declarative region, it's a sequential statement). This isn't valid VHDL and serves along with the question to demonstrate the value of providing a [mcve]. For questions there are errors to be addressed, for answers the validity can be checked (no hopefully).